# Running Perl Script from Command Line?

Tags: perl, perl-express

I have perl express 2.5 loaded on my server.  I would like to be able to run my perl scripts using a command line so they can be scheduled rather than manually bringing up the script in Perl Express and clicking on the run command.  Is there a way to execute the script from a command line using this version of Perl or do I need to download a newer or more robust version of the Perl Engine.

Comment: @dougEfresh — Perl Express is Windows only.

Answer (score 15):

You need to export the Perl interpreter (usually named `perl`) to your path. Then you can simply do

```
perl path/to/script.pl
```

In UNIX-based systems you are also able to run the scripts directly if you prepend

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

to the scripts and give them executable permissions (you might need to replace `/usr/bin/perl` with the path to your Perl interpreter).

Answer (score 6):

According to [the documentation](http://www.perl-express.com/getperl.html):

> Perl Express is not tied to a specific Perl port and should work with any build for Windows.

and [the system requirements](http://www.perl-express.com/download.html):

> Windows 98/Me/2000/XP/2003, **Perl Interpreter**

So you, presumably, have a separate Perl distribution already installed somewhere. That should have a `perl.exe` executable that you can use to run your script.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to give perl command and the path of your perl script.
example :

```
D:\Project\dir>perl <path_of_perl_script .pl>
```

Comment: sorry,
D:\Project\dir>perl <path to perl script .pl>

Comment: Instead of commenting your edits, edit your answer by clicking on `edit` button